# Can I insert exponents in a textbox (VB 2008-10)?

Tags: vb.net, equation, algebra

I have been Googling out for many days on how to solve a linear equation programatically. I have in my calculator app, a form `frmLEquation` and a textbox `txtEquation` where the user enters the equations like `2x^2 = 32`. I searched many webpages but I could not find the exact answer. Here, how do I add an exponent, which is of smaller font size than the others to a variable for example *2x*? I found this webpage [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/visual-basic-4-5-6/threads/233923/exponent-in-textbox-or-label), but I don't know how to interpret the code.

Please help me with the above situation. In case you have doubts/clarifications etc, please respond back.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a Rich Textbox instead of a regular textbox control.

Comment: so... how would I go about it?

Comment: @SandyMan - Read the documentation for the RichTextBox control.  Start with the Select method and then look at the SelectionFont property.